# Batch file crashing after unzipping an archive

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I have created two batch files, one which installs several files to specific directories and one which runs files from those directories. The Installer:

```
@ECHO off
CD /D %~dp0
SET location=%cd%
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates\" MD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates\Files"
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates\Files\Updating 3D Drone Coordinates.bat" XCOPY /s "%location%\Files" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates\Files"
```

The other:

```
@ECHO off
SET /p photos="Enter path to directory: "
SET location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates
CD %photos%
START /WAIT "" "%location%\Files\RinexPrep.exe"
FOR /r %photos% %%a in ("Rinex.txt") DO SET file=%%~nxa
START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NRCan CGS\PPP direct\PPP direct.exe" "Updating 3D" %file%
CD %location%
powershell Expand-Archive Rinex_full_output.zip '%location%'
FOR /r %location% %%a in ("Rinex.pos") DO SET file=%%~nxa
PAUSE
CD %photos%
DEL %photos%\Rinex.txt
REN Rinex.pos Rinex.txt
MOVE %location%\Rinex.txt %photos%
FOR /r %location%\Files %%a in ("GetDronePos.m") DO SET file=%%~nxa
move %location%\Files\%file% %photos%
matlab -wait -batch "try; run('%photos%\GetDronePos.m'); catch; end; quit;"
move %photos%\%file% %location%\Files
PAUSE
```

The photos directory refers to a folder with a group of jpegs and a .obs file with GPS data. The program RinexPrep.exe finds the .obs file, edits this file and renames it as Rinex.txt. The PPP Direct.exe sends this file to a third party service which downloads a zip file to the location directory. After unzipping this file, the program crashes at some point before the matlab command. This matlab script requires a file Rinex.pos from the third party zip file and all the images to be in the same directory as it. Can anyone discern what may be causing the program to crash?

Comment: Double quote paths with spaces e.g. `FOR /r "%location%" %%a in …` or `move "%location%\Files\%file%" "%photos%"` etc.

Comment: You should certainly appropriately doublequote each of `location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Updating 3D Coordinates`, `%photos%`, `%location%`, `%photos%`, `%file%`, `%photos%\Rinex.txt`, `%location%\Rinex.txt %photos%`, `%location%\Files`, `%location%\Files\%file% %photos%`, and `%photos%\%file% %location%\Files` as any or all of them could contain problematic characters.

Comment: With the lines `FOR /r %photos% %%a in ("Rinex.txt") DO SET file=%%~nxa`, `FOR /r %location% %%a in ("Rinex.pos") DO SET file=%%~nxa`, and `FOR /r %location%\Files %%a in ("GetDronePos.m") DO SET file=%%~nxa`, the very best you could hope for is that `%file%` would resolve to `Rinex.txt`, `Rinex.pos` and `GetDronePos.m`, which means that you could just use `SET "file=Rinex.txt"`, `SET "file=Rinex.pos"`, and `SET "file=GetDronePos.m"` respectively. This would be even worse if one of `Rinex.pos`, and/or `GetDronePos.m` weren't located, as the variable would point to `Rinex.txt` or `Rinex.pos`.

Comment: However, those `For /r` commands are not doing what you think they are, which I'd assume is supposed to be retrieving the location of those files. Not that it matters, because you're only setting it to the name, and extension, and completely ignoring its drive, and path. There are far too many things wrong with your provided code for me to even begin to look into your reported issue. Perhaps it would be easier if you were to comment your code, or explain in the body text of your question exactly what is supposed to be happening throughout. This would help us to assist you with greater focus.